# Slider navigation menu in jquery for iPhone app

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html, css

http://media02.hongkiat.com/mobile-navi-with-jquery/demo/index.html

http://indiqo.eu/demos/hotcake/

The two samples as above of menu slider navigation menu in jquery for mobile as web app but neither works as iPhone app (phonegap / xcode). It works brilliant for web app but sadly not on iphone app.

Does slider navigation menu in jquery for iPhone app? exist or is there working examples that I can source or buy the code?

Or can anyone make it work the slider navigation menu in iPhone app? Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved.

The solution:

```
enter code here`<script src="js/1.7_jquery.min.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` will not work in native `iOS` apps.

You can try to use [ZUUIRevealController](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/zuuirevealcontroller) for this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. May I ask, can you mix **ZUUIRevealController** by adding it on Xcode and HTML5 as phonegap? The reason I'm asking because you can add splash page etc on resource folder of the xcode so I've some idea and try to implement the **ZUUIRevealController** on Xcode.

Comment: Not sure - I not used phonegap yet.